# node-addon-api how to pass int pointer back and forth between JS and C/C++

Tags: c++, c, node-addon-api

I have the following backend functions:

```
// foo.c

void cStart(pid_t* pid)
{
  *pid = getpid();

  // event-loop keep running until receive SIGINT signal
}

void cStop(pid_t* pid)
{
  kill(*pid, SIGINT);
}
```

```
// addon.cpp

#include "addon.h"
#include "foo.h"

Napi::Number addon::run_pipeline_wrapped(const Napi::CallbackInfo &info)
{
  Napi::Env env = info.Env();

  // get the buffer from JS, pass it to cStart to be modified in-place [?]
  cStart(pid_t* pid);
}

Napi::Number addon::kill_pipeline_wrapped(const Napi::CallbackInfo &info)
{ 
  Napi::Env env = info.Env();

  // get the modified (by cStart) buffer from JS, pass it to cStop [?]
  cStop(pid_t* pid);
}
```

From the front-end, when the start button is clicked, a C process will start running until it receive a SIGINT signal and when the stop button is clicked, SIGINT signal is sent to the running C process. int* will travel as follow: JS (start button clicked) -> C/C++ (cStart modified int* in place so int* is not explicitly returned to JS) -> JS (stop button clicked) -> C/C++). So how do I pass an int pointer back and forth between JS and C/C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to pass pointer to JS.

You can use a global state instead:

```
// foo.c

pid_t* my_pid;

void cStart(void)
{
  my_pid = getpid(); // save the pid

  // event-loop keep running until receive SIGINT signal
}

void cStop(void)
{
  // kill the process from earlier
  kill(*my_pid, SIGINT);
}
```

Note, however this assumed that you had only one which isn't changed by anything else between calling `cStart` and calling `cEnd`. So in `cEnd` it should kill the same process on which the `start` button has been clicked.

Your C++ code will then look like this:

```
// addon.cpp

#include "addon.h"
#include "foo.h"

Napi::Number addon::run_pipeline_wrapped(const Napi::CallbackInfo &info)
{
  Napi::Env env = info.Env();
  cStart();
}

Napi::Number addon::kill_pipeline_wrapped(const Napi::CallbackInfo &info)
{ 
  Napi::Env env = info.Env();
  cStop();
}
```